# Laravel lazy eager loading

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck in this topic for an hour, I don't see anything that I'm missing. I'm trying to do a lazy eager load:

```
$p = Project::all();
$p = $p->load('skills', 'user', 'comments', 'suggests');
var_dump($p->skills());
```

but that throws out an error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::skills()
```

Comment: Are you meaning to say ```var_dump($p->skills);``` maybe?

Comment: @VictorBjelkholm then `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$skills`

Comment: Can you post the code in your Project model where you have the relationships defined? Do you have it listed as "skill" instead of "skills"?

Comment: @ChrisG yes, it works by `::with()` but fails on this kind of call I used.

Comment: @revo I'm not sure from just this information. I tried a simple setup and it worked as expected. Can you provide more code either through here or a github gist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dont assign $p->load() to $p.

```
$p = Project::all();
$p->load('skills', 'user', 'comments', 'suggests');
var_dump($p->skills());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to `load` relations on a collection instead of a `Model` because `$p` contains a collection of `Models` so this code won't work

```
$p = Project::all();
$p = $p->load('skills', 'user', 'comments', 'suggests');
var_dump($p->skills()); <-- $p is a collection not a Model
```

You can use a loop or use an index in the collection to specify the `Model` for which you want to load the relations like:

```
$p = Project::all();
$p = $p->load('skills', 'user', 'comments', 'suggests');

// Get the first Model from collection and load it's first
// skill from collection of skills objects
dd($p->first()->skills()->first());
```

Or use an index to specify the item in the collection, like:

```
$skills = $p->get(2)->skills()->get(); // Get skills from second Project, 1st = 1
dd($skills->get(2)); // Get second skill item from collection of skills
```

Also you may run a loop

```
$p = Project::all();
foreach($p as $project) {
    $skills = $project->skills()->get();
    dd($skills->first());
    dd($skills->get(2)) // 2nd item/skill, 1st = 1 (not 0)

    // Or another loop
    foreach($skills as $skill) {
       // Use $skill->field_name
    }
}
```